# How can I make a switch for ids with a click event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have been looking for this quite a long time here so I might as well ask.

I'm looking for a switch in Jquery like this pseudocode:

```
switch($(idvariable).click)
{
     case $someid: break; //if the user clicked this id, something happens
     case $someotherid: break; // if the user clicked another id with name "someotherid"
     case $yetanotherid: break; // ditto
}
```

Is this possible?

The expected behavior is the following:

If span 1 is clicked something happens. If span 2 is clicked something else happens. Each span has an id, but this should apply to any element be it div span or whatever. For instance if div with given id is clicked then x happens, if span with given id is clicked then y happens.

The point of doing this is not having to do 1000 `$("#blabla").click( function` etc... The point is grouping them since they have very similar behaviour.

In my case what I want to do is if given element with given id is clicked then increment given hidden element value. The SAME happens if another element with another id is clicked. In addition to this some CSS may have to be performed.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What did you tried?

Comment: you could use .toggle(). this function toggle state of a class, or anything.

Comment: @Alex toggle event has been removed from jQuery 1.9: https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/  And anyway, seems this has nothing to do with question (but with title i'd say yes...) ;)

Comment: you are kidding me ? oh ok then I should learn from answers here ;)

Comment: I am stuck as I don't know how to proceed. It's not that I haven't tried anything I have tried! I have looked for the answer here in SO and elsewhere and I didn't find anything. I'm not asking for fun you know...

Comment: You'd have better to explain expected behaviour, why would you need to get element ID? I guess you could just use one common handler and no need of any switch inside it

Comment: @A.Wolff I developed what I'm trying to do further. What do you mean by a common handler?

Comment: My answer should work

Comment: Thx for the update but still missing the important part, what should happen on click regarding different ID? This is this part which could be refactorised i guess

Comment: @A.Wolff Done, tell me if you need further clarification.

Comment: Depending your HTML markup, this could be done using instead any transversal method or index to target specifc hidden element regarding which element is clicked, e.g using index: http://jsfiddle.net/dtafv5ax/

Comment: @A.Wolff Nice! Very interesting I didn't know that selector existed. Very useful. I'm not sure if I can use it in this particular case however, I have to think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use class to bind click event (or list all id's)

```
<button class='click-me' id='a1'>1</button>
<button class='click-me' id='a2'>2</button>
<button class='click-me' id='a3'>3</button>

$('.click-me').click(function () {
    switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
        case 'a1':
             break;
        case 'a2':
             break;
        case 'a3':
             break;
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked. I advise using .prop instead of .attr > see Notorious Pet's answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).on('click', 'selector', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    switch(id) {
        case 'home': 
            //
            break;
        case 'contact':
            //
            break;
        default:
            console.log('No id');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the code from @Justinas but it makes no sense, since this code:

```
$('.click-me').click(function () {
    switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
        case 'a1':
             doSomethingA();
             break;
        case 'a2':
             doSomethingB();
             break;
        case 'a3':
             doSomethingC();
             break;
    }
});
```

can and SHOULD (for readability purposes) be replaced with:

```
$('#a1').click(doSomethingA);
$('#a2').click(doSomethingB);
$('#a3').click(doSomethingC);
```

Comment: Why it should be replaced? If you have 20 elements, than do 20 bindings... That must be written manually...?

Comment: @Justinas But in your case using switch, you still have to write 20 different cases

Comment: but the question was "how to use switch", not "what is the best way to do stuff" :)

Comment: Random is right. And It shouldn't be replaced. For readability purposes and saving code lines a switch is much more practical.

Comment: @Joze Sorry but i'm disagree, a switch case isn't for me more readable than binding specific handler, but that's quite opinion based

Comment: @A.Wolff at least we can agree we disagree :-)

Comment: @A.Wolff But if you wish for 5 selectors to do same thing, than you have to repeat same code anyway...

Comment: @Justinas If you want 5 selectors to do the same thing, then you can combine them like `$('#a1,#a2,#a3').click(doSomethingCommon)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function callSwitch(value) {
    switch(value) {
        case 'someid':
        break;

        //etc..
    }
}

$(".switchclick").on('click', function() {
    var myid = $(this).prop('id');
    callSwitch(myid);
});
```

Comment: `$(this).prop('id')` or `$(this).attr('id')`, ok but why not just `this.id` ? :)

Comment: Sometimes this.id doesn't work for whatever reason, and on SO I always want to post the answer I'm sure is going to work and not take chances of getting downvoted or not getting the accept.

Comment: your only motivation is reputation ? oh... :p

Comment: @Random No, actually if that was my only motivation I wouldn't be on here.  But my rep is still low, I cannot even do some basic things without getting approved, like edit posts and what not.  And it is very rare that I can find a review queue that is not empty since I only have access to 3 of them right now along with a million other people.  So yeah rep is important at this stage, but not everything, by a longshot.